# Could not load assembly. Module not found. PC without VisualStudio

Tags: .net, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, reflection, .net-assembly

I'm a newcomer to StackOverflow. Beforehand, please, forgive the faults on my english.

I have the following problem:

I'm building an application in VC++/CLI (.NET 4.0) that uses a plug-in system using reflection. All the plug-ins are developed by myself too.

Each plugin is a assembly (dll) detected and loaded at runtime. The main application and each plugins references an third assembly that only contains a class interface for *safe-cast* in the load-reflection step. This assembly builds to the same folder that the main app and all the plugins.

The problem is: when I execute-debug (F5) the application inside Visual Studio, everything works fine. Also, when the app is executed outside VS, it works OK too. But, when the app is executed on a PC without VS, I got the following error:
**"Could not load file or assembly 'PluginInterface.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found"**.

The error seems to happen when the plugin assemblies are first loaded (Assembly::LoadFrom(filename)) in the main application. Can't be sure, since as I said, the computers where the error occur, don't have VS installed for debugging, or else the error does not occur. This point is the very first use of those assemblies in the application.

The deployment PCs all have .NET 4.0 and the VC++ redist installed.

Why is this happening? What can i do? As you can see, this problem is holding the deployment.

Comment: Missing DLL, best way to find out which when you don't have any debugging tools available is to use SysInternals' Process Monitor.  Towards the end the trace, you'll see your app searching for the DLL and not finding it.

Comment: Is this a Debug build? If so, it won't find the Debug runtime DLLs because they are not redistributable.

Comment: It occurs in Debug and Release builds.

Comment: I begun to use Fuslogvw.exe. But it doesn't show any log to analyze

Comment: for Windows x64 I have to build for x64? x86 (win32) referenced assemblies fail in load time?

Comment: FIXED!! using the "Process Monitor" utility from Microsoft, I realize that some assemblies dlls, deep in the calling/reference cascade, were build in debug mode (by example, they were calling MSVCRT110D.dll. See the "D"?), so they fail at load time, crashing their caller/referencer. Must check carefully all dependence and build configurations and outputs. Heavy work... By now, the whole solution (two solutions really) contains 52 projects and going up.

Comment: thnks Hans!!, I already used ProcMon and Dependz, but fail to notice the error. Your pointing make me try again, and gotcha!!

Answer (score 1):

FIXED!! using the "Process Monitor" utility from Microsoft, I realize that some assemblies dlls, deep in the call/reference cascade, were build in debug mode (by example, they were calling MSVCRT110D.dll. See the "D"?), so they fail at load time, crashing their caller/referencer. Must check carefully all dependence and build configurations and outputs. Heavy work... By now, the whole solution (two solutions really) contains 52 projects and going up.
thnks Hans!!, I already used ProcMon and Dependz, but fail to notice the error. Your pointing make me try again, and gotcha!!